# Sum of Stresses in a Control Volume along $x$-axis

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, navier-stokes

We were looking in class at the sum of forces, acting on surface $x$, of a control volume $dV$.

I see from the equation, the first term is the normal force, and then the rate of change of the force wrt $x$ and so on.

However I don't understand how or why the opposite terms were added. At first I assumed it was the some of stresses but in opposite direction, but i noticed their rate of change was not included. So I do not know what is going on.

Thank you kindly for your help and time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your last line has some errors and should read (with two denominators changed)

$$=\left(\frac{\partial\sigma_{xx}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\tau_{yx}}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial\tau_{zx}}{\partial z}\right)dx\,dy\,dz$$

2. By "there opposite terms", I think you're asking why $[\sigma_{xx}(dy\,dz)+\tau_{xy}(dx\,dz)+\tau_{zx}(dx\,dy)]$ is subtracted. The reason is that we're performing a force balance on the element in all three directions to obtain the net force in the $x$ direction $F_{\rm{stress,}x}$. We're also applying a Taylor series expansion to the stress, which is assumed to vary inside the element.

   Take the stress $\sigma_{xx}$, for example. On the left side of the element, call it $\sigma_{xx}(\text{at }x=0)$. On the right side, call it $\sigma_{xx}(\text{at }x=dx)$. So we have a force acting to the left with magnitude $$\sigma_{xx}(\text{at }x=0)\,dy\,dz,$$ and a force acting to the right with magnitude $$\sigma_{xx}(\text{at }x=dx)\,dy\,dz.$$ Equilibrium in the $x$-direction (taking rightward forces as positive) thus gives $$-\left[\sigma_{xx}(\text{at }x=0)\,dy\,dz\right]+\left[\sigma_{xx}(\text{at }x=dx)\,dy\,dz\right]=0,$$ or, with the Taylor expansion, $$-\left[\sigma_{xx}(\text{at }x=0)\,dy\,dz\right]+\left[\sigma_{xx}(\text{at }x=0)\,dy\,dz+\frac{\partial \sigma_{xx}(\text{at }x=0)}{\partial x}dx\right]$$ $$=\frac{\partial \sigma_{xx}(\text{at }x=0)}{\partial x}dx,$$
   or $\frac{\partial \sigma_{xx}}{\partial x}dx$ for simplicity, which is one component of the expression above. The same process is applied to the $\tau_{xy}$ and $\tau_{xz}$ stresses, each of which also applies an $x$-direction force. Does this make sense?

   (If it helps, if there's something that's not clicking, the same derivation appears [here](http://www.eng.uc.edu/%7Ebeaucag/RyanBreese/Mechanics/mechanics.htm) and [here](http://www.idc-online.com/technical_references/pdfs/mechanical_engineering/Equations_of_Motion.pdf).)